# Node Express get user from database in middle ware

Tags: mongodb, express, nodes, mern

Is it worth it to get the user from the database in each middleware call?
is this the right approach for Node?

```
   jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'), (err, decoded) => {
    if(err) res.status(403).send('invalid token')
    else{
        req.user = decoded;
        axios 
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/users/${req.user._id}`)
        .then( res => {req.user = res.data; next();} )
        .catch( err => res.status(400).send("invalid token") )
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

when uses `jwt`, usually `user_roll` and `user_id` like information that may be required in subsequent requests and has no security issues, put in `jwt` payload until user send a request ,after verify you can access to `user_id` and `user_roll` easily , in your approach after verify you want more data about user that there is not in payload jwt, you must to request to get more data...also if you want more data and you won't to put the data in payload, for quick access can use [Redis](https://redis.io/)

Comment: I was using this approach earlier to put user_roles in jwt but, in my application when user_role is changed in DB how can i also change token?

Comment: when user_roll changes, your user must to login again, and create a new jwt with new role, This is the right method